# How does Trigger work in Cosmos DB Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am not able to understand how Trigger works in Cosmos DB Emulator. Please explain me how it is used.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you do and don't understand?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by Trigger? Do you mean the [pre/post Database Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cosmos-db/triggers) or the [Cosmos DB Trigger in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions)?

Comment: I want to learn about pre/post Database Triggers in Cosmos DB Emulator.I went through a few sources but could not understand how a trigger is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you need to know that [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#triggers) in cosmos db is different from the [azure function cosmos db trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function). It can't be executed automatically. It should be defined specifically when you call the sdk method,please refer to the sample on the official document.

Create trigger:

```
string triggerId = "trgPreValidateToDoItemTimestamp";
Trigger trigger = new Trigger
{
    Id =  triggerId,
    Body = File.ReadAllText($@"..\js\{triggerId}.js"),
    TriggerOperation = TriggerOperation.Create,
    TriggerType = TriggerType.Pre
};
Uri containerUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("myDatabase", "myContainer");
await client.CreateTriggerAsync(containerUri, trigger);
```

Of course,you could create the trigger via cosmos db portal or emulator UI:

[image]

Then you need to define the name of the trigger you created when you use corresponding sdk method. For example,you created Pre trigger and Trigger Operation as `Create`,then you could use below code to active it:

```
Uri containerUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("myDatabase", "myContainer");
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PreTriggerInclude = new List<string> { "<your trigger name>" } };
await client.CreateDocumentAsync(containerUri, newItem, requestOptions);
```

Comment: Sir, I understood till the part where the trigger is created.Can i know  where I should save and run the above code(the code which is used to activate the trigger)?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @VarunKumar That's the cosmso db c# sdk code,do you have any experiences with that,about any development?

Comment: I don't have any experience with it. I am completely new to the field.It would be very helpful if I am provided with some source to learn it.

Comment: @VarunKumar Understand. So if you want to learn more about cosmos db,firstly, you could view microsoft official quickstart like how to use this service:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/

Comment: @VarunKumar The way i mentioned in my answer is using .net sdk to use cosmos db service,no matter it is emulator or real service.About the differences bewteen them, you could refer  to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#differences-between-the-emulator-and-the-service

Comment: @VarunKumar It depends what dev language you are familiar with. For example,.net ,java ,js or python .

Comment: @VarunKumar Hi,any updates? Any further issue you need help?

Comment: Sir, the mentioned code doesn't include a connection string or something of that sort to connect to the Emulator. Shouldn't it include something like that to activate the trigger in my database?If yes, can I please know the syntax? Thank you.